# wcf data services windows authentication problem

Tags: wcf-data-services

I have a WCF data service and in the web.config I have used

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

I am trying to avoid any binding configuration, so have used none at this point.

I am accessing the service from a WPF application.

IIS is configured for "Windows Authentication" only.

When I access the service, I set the credentials

```
_proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

But I get an error "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials."

If I change it to the following, the service works correctly :

```
_proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "$password", "Domain");
```

When tracing this in Fiddler, I notice that when I use the DefaultNetworkCredentials the NTLM Auth header is

Domain:

User: username@Domain.com

Host: PC-59

When using the successful new NetworkCredential("username", "$password", "MyDomain"), the Auth header is

Domain: MyDomain

User: username

Host: PC-59

PS.  For the record, here is my service configuration :

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>          
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />          
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: Could you show the server configuration for the WCF service.

Comment: Whilst I accept I might have to use configuration to solve this, I am trying to use the "zero configuration experience".  I have added it to the question just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the authentication blog series Alex is writing here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/tags/authentication/

It describes the different auth schemes and how they behave. One of which is the above (and it also describes why the client makes two requests and how to overcome that if you want).

Hope this helps,

Monica Frintu

Comment: Thanks for the link. The problem is that it states the following, but in my case the user has access to the server but only the second option works  : 

MyDataContext ctx = new MyDataContext(uri); 
ctx.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;  

The example above makes sense if your client application is running under a windows account that has access to the server. If not however you will have to create a new set of NetworkCredentials and use them instead.

ctx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential( 
    "username", 
    "password", 
    "domain");